# TypeError constructor returned NULL in wayland session matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, gtk3, wayland, mouse-cursor

When trying to run matplotlib pyplot, and setting the backend to gtk3agg or gtk3cairo, the following error is encountered in wayland session. The same code works fine in Xorg, or using Qt backend

```
Gdk-Message: 12:41:05.918: Unable to load fleur from the cursor theme
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py", line 40, in <module>
    cursors.MOVE:          Gdk.Cursor.new(Gdk.CursorType.FLEUR),
TypeError: constructor returned NULL
```

There are similar discussion and questions on the forum but none seem to give a definite answer on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in matplotlib; it's using deprecated API, with the main reason for the deprecation being that this kind of API explicitly won't work on all kinds of graphical sessions.

The API they should be using in this case is [`Gdk.Cursor.new_from_name(Gdk.Display.get_default(), "move")`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gdk-3.0/classes/Cursor.html#Gdk.Cursor.new_from_name).

Except for patching their source and distributing the modified version, the best solution is to create an issue in their issue tracker.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Have raised the issue in matplotlib issue tracker

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/19405